# Fire javascript event listener from native Android code using Worklight

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

I'm reading the following tutorial:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/android_combining_native_and_web_controls_in_cordova_based_applications?lang=en.

I'm trying to follow the tutorial and integrate it in my app with ReactJS. I created a plugin to call native and javascript code, my Cordova plugin is in `HybirdBridge.java` and my javascript listener is in `NativeEventListener.js`. My code can be found here: https://github.com/nguyengiangdev/HybridBridge

I have a search button in the action bar. When I click the search button I try to invoke the javascript event but it throws a Null Pointer Exception in the `listenerCallbackContext`.

I don't know why? Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the MobileFirst Platform (formerly known as Worklight) Developer Center for more information on this topic.

The following link has various tutorials for Android, iOS and Windows Phone on how to add native functionality to hybrid applications.

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/adding-native-functionality/

Starting with Worklight 6.2 you can pass data back and forth between hybrid and native without creating your own Cordova plugin by using the following code:

**Hybrid to Native**

*Send*

```
var data = { someproperty : 1234 };
WL.App.sendActionToNative("doSomething", data);
```

**Hybrid to Native**

*Receive*

```
WL.getInstance().addActionReceiver(new WLActionReceiver() {
    void onActionReceived(String action, JSONObject data){
      // process received action
    }
});
```

**Native to Hybrid**

*Send*

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("someProperty", 12345);
WL.getInstance().sendActionToJS("doSomething", data);
```

*Receive*

```
WL.App.addActionReceiver ("MyActionReceiverId", function(received) {
    if (received.action === "doSomething"){ 
        // handle the data received
    }
});
```

For more information about this visit:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_sending_actions_native_to_js.html

**Other useful links:**

Getting Started with IBM MobileFirst Platform:

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started/

IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation v7 Knowledge Center:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/wl_welcome.html

Comment: There is also a blog post about ReactJS and MFP: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/04/03/react-js-and-mobilefirst-platform-foundation/